# Auto Switch tab......but stays on 2nd tab (as last tab)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Based on Bootstrap 3..... all I want is, the tab switch to 2nd tab after some time interval and stays.

I need jquery/javascript code fix this issue... kindly help me as I'm a newbie, many thanks...!!!

Here is the code of tab section:

```
                        <!-- Nav Tabs -->
                        <ul id="tabsnav" class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab-4" data-toggle="tab">Daily</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab-5" data-toggle="tab">Weekly</a></li>

                        </ul>


                        <!-- Tab Panels -->
                        <div style="min-height:400px;" class="tab-content">

                            <!-- Tab Content 1 -->
                            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab-4">

                                <p>Report Goes Here</p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Tab Content 2 -->
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-5">

                                <p>2 Report Goes Here</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- End Tab Panels -->

                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- End Page Content -->
```

Comment: So you want it to switch to 2nd tab and stay there?

Comment: yes , after loading of page....after about 2 to 3 seconds....it switch to 2nd tab......but don't go to first.....(no looping) stayed permanently to 2nd tab....

Comment: thats strange! well, have you included all the required js? like jQuery and others on whom Bootstrap is dependent on. Can you post some more of you html code?

Comment: I tried many Jquery code but didn't get

Comment: http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/layout/tabs3.php

Comment: check this link..... but on last tab it move to first one.....just don't want this feature

Comment: check this link,  http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/layout/tabs3_demo.html 

is this what you want? or you dont want to auto switch the tabs?

Comment: or do you want it to move to the last tab and stay there as long as you don't click on other tabs?

Comment: yes same thing as your example but after swicting to last tab it stops....that's it

Comment: can you share the javascript code for switching between tabs? that would be really helpful